# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Elements Without Adding Classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just picked up Bootstrap 4 for a new project after having been very comfortable around BS3 years ago.

I set everything up in a new project and added a basic `<p>` tag. That's it just a `<p>` tag. I began to resize my browser window, expecting to see nothing cool of course, but what happens? The text is responding to the size of the viewport... how?

I cannot for the life of me figure out how this is happening without adding containers, rows, columns or anything. Any explanations?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: `The text is responding to the size of the viewport`. How is it responding? Does it change size?

Comment: Nothing happens, texts stays like it is when resizing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGmNvp , you should have some custom style.

Comment: You may be missing some meta tags

Comment: @Troyer Sir, I tried your Codepen. If you copy the words "text text" and paste it multiple time inside the p tag, then resize screen, text repositions responsively.

Comment: @FabianSchöner it repositions itself in the viewport. Is this normal behavior with no extra classes?

Comment: @KeplerIO are u using a bootstrap container? The normal `container` does have fixed widths in the upper breakpoints and gets to a 100% width in xs viewport.

Comment: I am using nothing at all. Take for example, I just created a brand new fresh Angular app. Nothing except fresh app. Added p tag to test this again. Text acts like it has Bootstrap applied.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 and 4 do [redefine many things](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/) before you even start applying the more common stylings. [Paragraphs and Headings](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/#headings-and-paragraphs)